# .htaccess 301 redirection for wordpress network site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I tried with  this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.maindomain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.maindomain.com/wp-admin/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

but it's not working.
The behavior I want is for `subdomain.maindomain.com` too be automatically redirected to `subdomain.maindomain.com/wp-admin`

Comment: Please check out [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: when i open subdomain.maindomain.com it will automatically redirect to subdomain.maindomain.com/wp-admin

Comment: What doesnt work for you?